# Setting the path to the interpreter in Emacs for Perl debugging with perldb

Tags: perl, debugging, emacs

When I type `M-x perldb` to debug my Perl script, the debugging session fails, I think it is because I have a line at the beginning of my script that says:

```
use 5.010
```

The Emacs Perl debugger complains with:

```
 Perl v5.10.0 required--this is only v5.8.6,
 at /path/to/file
```

I think it's loading an old Perl interpreter (the default one installed in my system). However, I have a much newer interpreter installed on a different path, so how can I tell `perldb` in Emacs the path to the interpreter that I want it to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a version of `perldb.el` I see this code:

```
   (defvar perldb-command-name "perl"
     "*Pathname of Perl interpreter.")
```

I'm sure if you either redefine the value of this variable, or if you set your `PATH` environment variable so that `perl` invokes the 5.10 version of perl, things will work for you.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but it didn't work. Also, I think you need to add the prefix `gud-` to the variable name, i.e. from I have seen in a Google search, the variable name is `gud-perldb-command-name`

Comment: Actually, I don't even have `perldb.el`. Is it possible that the Perl debugger is now part of Emacs?

Comment: Which emacs are you using? `perldb` might come standard with your emacs distro, but it still will be implemented in emacs lisp, and there will be a `.el` source file for it.

I would also try setting `$PATH` to put your `perl` ahead of whatever perl is being found. Do this before starting up emacs.

Comment: Thanks user5402. I am running Emacs `23.1.1`. I looked for a `perldb.el` file everywhere in the system and could not find it. I have an alias `alias perl=/path/to/desired/perl` in my `.zshrc`, and when I run my perl scripts from the command line they run the right interpreter.

Comment: an alias won't work. you have to your PATH environment variable to include the directory that your 5.10 perl resides in, and that directory has to come before where the standard perl is located. What OS are you using?